# Angular2 setting proxy fails

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to access this URL using angular2 cli but getting error of access control

```
http://safety.trucksafetyinspection.co.ke/rest/v1/new/profile?access-token=my-token
```

I have added a `proxy.config.json` file as

```
{
  "/rest/v1/*":{
      "target":"http://safety.trucksafetyinspection.co.ke",
      "secure":false,
      "logLevel":"debug"
  }
}
```

But still am getting an error of

```
No Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin
```

In the package.config.json

```
"scripts": {
   "ng": "ng",
   "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json",
  },
```

So after `ng build` or `npm start` or even `ng serve` am still getting this error. What could be wrong?

**UPDATE**: The backend is in yii2 and ive setup cors filters as

```
public function behaviors()
{
  return [
    'corsFilter' => [
        'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
        'cors' => [
            // restrict access to
            'Origin' => ['*'],
            'Access-Control-Request-Method' => ['POST', 'PUT','OPTIONS','GET'],
            // Allow only POST and PUT methods
            'Access-Control-Request-Headers' => ['X-Wsse'],
            // Allow only headers 'X-Wsse'
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => true,
            // Allow OPTIONS caching
            'Access-Control-Max-Age' => 3600,
            // Allow the X-Pagination-Current-Page header to be exposed to the browser.
            'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' => ['X-Pagination-Current-Page'],
        ],

    ],
 ];
}
```

Comment: If you work behind a corporate proxy, the regular backend proxy configuration will not work if you try to proxy calls to any URL outside your local network. If this is your case, try to use corporate proxy https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/using-corporate-proxy.md  instead

Comment: do you see  `Proxy created: ...` message in logs after calling `npm start`?

Comment: what about during build when i ng build and deploy to  shared hosting this also fails

Comment: yes npm start i can see proxy created message

Comment: Can you add the auth process? Can you add the code in beforeAction() and the profile action?

Answer (score 0):

this does not sound like a proxy error to me. This sounds like a cross origin (CORS) issue. This happens when the src domain is not the same as the dest domain for certain browser requests.

e.g. src domain is woogle.com BUT dest domain is noogle.com

you have two options, either get your web server to rewrite requests

OR

add Access-Control headers to your backend server. These headers, if present, define which OTHER domains can make requests to your server.

For example ..

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://foo.example
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-PINGOTHER, Content-Type
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
```

How these headers are set on your server will depend on whether its Node Express, Apache, NGINX, etc

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS for more details